# Problem With Multiple PickerViews in one View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewcontroller, pickerview

So I am getting this strange problem as I try to use multiple PickerViews in one view controller. I have set it up so that I use an if / else if so that it checks which picker to put the correct data to. I have 3 pickers total, and the first two work fine, but the third one never shows any data. Here are the functions:

```
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView == sitePicker {
            return sitePickerData.count
        } else if pickerView == sizePicker {
            return sizePickerData.count
        } else if pickerView == profilePicker {
            return profilePickerData.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == sitePicker {
            return "\(sitePickerData[row])"
        } else if pickerView == sizePicker {
            return "\(sizePickerData[row])"
        } else if pickerView == profilePicker  {
            return "\(profilePickerData[row])"
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

the sitePickerData, sizePickerData, etc are string arrays which hold the options to scroll through on the picker. Once again, the first two work fine, but the third picker does not show any data from the array. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you set the delegate on `profilePicker`? How are you switching between pickers? It would help if you posted more code

Comment: Oh my God i forgot to set the delegate...thank you; I feel so dumb haha

Comment: LOL, it happens